# How to display the selected value in the dropdown while editing in laravel form?

Tags: laravel, forms

I have used three tables

```
user - id

roles - id, roles

role_user - user_id, role_id
```

I have retrieved data using `belongsToMany` relationship.

In my controller,

```
$this->data['roles'] = Role::pluck('name','id');

$this->data['get_roles'] = Employee::find($id)->user->roles()->get();

//In my form blade,

{{Form::select('role',$roles,$get_roles,['id'=> 'role', 'placeholder' => 'select'])}}
```

I want the selected value to be displayed in the dropdown while editing.

Comment: from the documentation you can set a default value like this `echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');`

Comment: You have to pass $get_roles as array of ids like $get_roles = array(1, 2) etc.

Comment: are you saying that i want to pass it as an array in the form.blade?